# Featured error : Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-platform, rubygems

I tried to install the gem **'parse-stack'** and I received this error :

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
>   In Gemfile:
>       parse-stack was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
>         activesupport (>= 4, < 5)
>
> ```
> rails (= 6.0.2) was resolved to 6.0.2, which depends on
>   activesupport (= 6.0.2)
> ```

I tried typing **rm Gemfile.lock** and after that **bundle install** but nothing happened. This is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

gem 'parse-stack'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: "`parse-stack was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on activesupport (>= 4, < 5)`" Does this not mean that you have to downgrade to Rails 5? On github parse-stack is at v1.8.0. Maybe call `gem 'parse-stack', '>= 1.8'` in your gemfile and try bundle again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but did not work. I received : Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    parse-stack (>= 1.8) was resolved to 1.8.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.1, < 6)

    rails (~> 6.0.2, >= 6.0.2.1) was resolved to 6.0.2.1, which depends on
      activesupport (= 6.0.2.1)

Comment: `gem list --remote 'parse-stack'` is giving me `parse-stack (1.8.0)` Check your settings for your gem sources. Also "did not work" is not helpful. Was the error the same? Did you try 'bundle update 'parse-stack'`?

Comment: Ok that is your answer. `parse-stack` does not think it can work with Rails above v6. `pares-stack` may not have tested with the latest Rails 6 above 6.0? The computer is very literal, (>= 4.2.1, < 6) does not contain 6.0.2.

Comment: In fact it says "<6" which means less than 6. Not equal to 6. i.e every version of 5, but no version of 6. Maybe check parse-stack's website for more info.

Comment: OK, their github gemfile says `< 7`. https://github.com/modernistik/parse-stack/blob/master/Gemfile.lock So maybe you need to update your sources or pull from their github repo directly.

Answer (score 0):

OK the rubygems.org site for `parse-stack` is stuck at `activesupport < 6, >= 4.2.1` I'm not sure why when it lists it as v1.8.0. But that is your hang up.

You can pull directly from github until they update the rubygems.org source with:

gem 'parse-stack', 'https://github.com/modernistik/parse-stack'

Comment: I have opened an issue on their github advising them that rubygems.org is stuck expecting a lower version than what their github expects.